# Mongoose Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-lambda

I'm creating an AWS Lambda API with Node JS. There's a template for the db connection itself, but when I run a test in Lambda I get an error and I believe the problem is the connection itself.

Here's the error message I get with Lambda test:

> START RequestId: 6b9eef97-9c54-44bc-8ecc-dfbec7e200e5 Version: $LATEST
>   2020-05-23T01:46:23.685Z    6b9eef97-9c54-44bc-8ecc-dfbec7e200e5    INFO    => using new database connection
>   2020-05-23T01:46:23.689Z    6b9eef97-9c54-44bc-8ecc-dfbec7e200e5    ERROR   (node:8) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
>   2020-05-23T01:46:23.726Z    6b9eef97-9c54-44bc-8ecc-dfbec7e200e5    ERROR   (node:8) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
>   2020-05-23T01:46:23.828Z    6b9eef97-9c54-44bc-8ecc-dfbec7e200e5    ERROR   Unhandled Promise Rejection     {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0","reason":{"errorType":"SyntaxError","errorMessage":"Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0","stack":["SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0","    at JSON.parse ()","    at /var/task/handler.js:17:22","    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0","    at process. (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)","    at process.emit (events.js:310:20)","    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)","    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)"]}
>   END RequestId: 6b9eef97-9c54-44bc-8ecc-dfbec7e200e5
>   REPORT RequestId: 6b9eef97-9c54-44bc-8ecc-dfbec7e200e5  Duration: 186.61 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 34 MB
>   Unknown application error occurred

DB.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
let isConnected;

module.exports = connectToDatabase = () => {
  if (isConnected) {
    console.log("=> using existing database connection");
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  console.log("=> using new database connection");
  return mongoose.connect(process.env.DB).then((db) => {
    isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState;
  });
};
```

Handler.js

```
"use strict";

const connectToDatabase = require("./db");
const Lead = require("./leads.model.js");

require("dotenv").config({ path: "./variables.env" });

module.exports.hello = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log("Hello World");
  callback(null, "Hello World");
};

module.exports.create = (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  connectToDatabase().then(() => {
    Lead.create(JSON.parse(event.body))
      .then((lead) =>
        callback(null, {
          statusCode: 200,
          body: JSON.stringify(lead),
        })
      )
      .catch((err) =>
        callback(null, {
          statusCode: err.statusCode || 500,
          headers: { "Content-Type": "text/plain" },
          body: "Could not create the lead.",
        })
      );
  });
};
```

variables.env

```
DB=mongodb+srv://dbUser:password@api-jodqc.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Comment: That usually means that whatever you're trying to parse is `undefined`.  Since I only see `JSON.parse()` in one spot, I'm guessing `event.body` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever I see `Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`, it usually means `JSON.parse` is trying to parse `undefined`.  Looking at the code, I only see you executing parse in one spot

```
Lead.create(JSON.parse(event.body))
```

I'm guessing when you execute the Lambda, you're passing in an object that looks like a lead directly, so maybe something like below.

```
{
  isALead: true
}
```

Instead, you need to test with an object that looks like

```
{
  body: "{ \"isALead\": true }"
}
```